# Using QMutex::tryLock and QMutexLocker

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, mutex

I have a background function that currently has something like follows:

```
void SomeClass::someFunction()
{
    if (!_mutex.tryLock())
    {
        // i want to know the mutex is locked, and then exit the function
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        _mutex.unlock();
    }

    QMutexLocker locker(_mutext);

    // do some stuff that **could** throw an exception
}
```

My dilemma concerns the `_mutex.unlock()` and `QMutextLocker` statement.

If the `_mutex` is locked, then I want to know about it. If it's not, then I want lock it. The problem is that I want to use `QMutexLocker` to lock `_mutex` for the bulk of the function. It's possible that the function could throw an exception, so manually unlocking `_mutex` could be difficult and error prone.

The above solution works but what concerns me is that sometime between the `_mutex.unlock()` and the deceleration of `QMutexLocker` something else could come along and lock the mutex.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to do some work while waiting for the lock?

Comment: I've updated the code to better reflect what I want to do. If the mutex is locked, I want do some stuff and then exit the function.

Comment: Same problem here. Also would like to have a QMutexLocker that supports tryLock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

QMutexLocker clearly doesn't do quite what you need here, but you can write your own RAII wrapper easily enough:

```
class MutexTryLocker {
  QMutex &m_;
  bool locked_;
public:
  MutexTryLocker(QMutex &m) : m_(m), locked_(m.tryLock()) {}
  ~MutexTryLocker() { if (locked_) m_.unlock(); }
  bool isLocked() const { return locked_; }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
void SomeClass::someFunction() {
    MutexTryLocker locker(_mutex);

    if (!locker.isLocked()) {
        // we didn't get the lock, so return
        return;
    }

    // do some stuff that **could** throw an exception
}
```

Note this locker is just sample code: a production version should probably be explicitly noncopyable.

---

Historical note: JBL's comment referred to a paragraph addressing a sentence no longer in the question. I'll paraphrase it as:

> ... something else could come along and lock the mutex

If it's possible, it *will* happen. If it's unlikely, it will happen *only after* you deploy it/scale it up/sell it to a customer.

Comment: +1 even just for the first statement. In this business, [One in a million is next tuesday](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and ended up using the equivalent standard components instead of the Qt ones, as their lock_guard is able to handle an already locked mutex. If that is an option for someone, you could do it this way:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex _mutex;

void SomeClass::someFunction()
{
    if (!_mutex.try_lock())
    {
        // i want to know the mutex is locked, and then exit the function
        return;
    }

    // The lock_guard overtakes the already locked mutex
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex, std::adopt_lock);

    // do some stuff that **could** throw an exception
}
```